# modify the picture size in animation-list

Tags: android

I want to realize the picture shown dynamic in the animation – list. But I don't know how to modify the picture size. Because I want to the picture display in px style not dip. But the picture in animation - list is displayed dip default. 
How to modify animation - list the picture size? And how to change into the the picture display px default?

Comment: are you trying to resize your images in your animation? like make them bigger or smaller?

Comment: for a given density, pixels are congru to dips